# How to check properly that ILogger.LogCritical has been called with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, nsubstitute

I have some hard times with NSubstitute to check whether the method `ILogger.LogCritical(...)` has been called.

For example with the code below:

```
[Fact]
public void TestNSubstituteAgain()
{
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<StockService>>();
    logger.LogCritical(new Exception(), "Hey lads!");
    logger.Received().Log(
        LogLevel.Critical, 
        Arg.Any<EventId>(), 
        Arg.Any<object>(), 
        Arg.Any<Exception>(),
        Arg.Any<Func<object, Exception, string>>()
        );
}
```

I am getting that exception:

```
Rm.Combo.App.Tests.VirtualParcels.Services.StockServiceTest.TestNSubstituteAgain

NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive a call matching:
    Log<Object>(Critical, any EventId, any Object, any Exception, any Func<Object, Exception, String>)
Actually received no matching calls.

   at NSubstitute.Core.ReceivedCallsExceptionThrower.Throw(ICallSpecification callSpecification, IEnumerable`1 matchingCalls, IEnumerable`1 nonMatchingCalls, Quantity requiredQuantity)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.CheckReceivedCallsHandler.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Core.CallRouter.Route(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.ProxyIdInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy_2.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Rm.Combo.App.Tests.VirtualParcels.Services.StockServiceTest.TestNSubstituteAgain() in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\combo\api\Rm.Combo.App.Tests\VirtualParcels\Services\StockServiceTest.cs:line 99
```

```cs
// 1] Ok the call I am making is that ext. method below:
public static void LogCritical(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
{
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, exception, message, args);
}

// 2] Which forwards to that other ext. method below:
public static void Log(this ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
{
    logger.Log(logLevel, 0, exception, message, args);
}

// 3] and... then here (still an ext. method tho):
public static void Log(this ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args)
{
    if (logger == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, new FormattedLogValues(message, args), exception, _messageFormatter);
}

// 4] to finally end up with this "direct" interface method:
void Log<TState>(
LogLevel logLevel,
EventId eventId,
TState state,
Exception exception,
Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);
// Note: which is supposedly what I am gonna ask NSubstitute to check against, right? (since we cannot use NSubstitute `Received` method on ext. method, it has to be the corresponding instance method)
```

Note: `FormattedLogValues` is an `internal struct` so I really had to use `Arg.Any<object>`.

When I check the calls actually received,I see that the logger has a call and I am not too sure to how it differs from I am asserting against. Like I am putting a breakpoint on something like `var re = logger.ReceivedCalls();` while debugging my unit test:

[image]

I really don't know what is not considered as proper parametes(s) of the NSubstitute `Received()` assertion.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Arg.Any<ValueType>`? Since `FormattedLogValues` is `struct`

Comment: There is GitHub [issue](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/597) for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Moq for that particular kind of tests:

```cs
// Defining an extension method
public static void IsLogReceived(this IMock<ILogger<StockService>>logger, LogLevel level, int count = 1) =>
    logger.Verify(x =>
        x.Log(level,
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), 
        Times.Exactly(count));

// [...]

// and using the ext. method like that:
[Fact]
public void TestNSubstituteAgain()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<StockService>>();
    var logger = loggerMock.Object;
    logger.LogCritical(new Exception(), "Hey lads!");
    loggerMock.IsLogReceived(LogLevel.Critical);
}
```

It's not that accurate but depending on what's going on in the method scope, that can get the job done.

That being said, I concede that the most precise way of achieving that would be to declare a wrapping type.

Resources that helped me a bit:

- https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/597
- https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1319

Answer (score 3):

I would use `ReceivedWithAnyArgs()` (https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/) if matching on the parameters is very difficult. NSubstitute is nice if things are simple. If it gets too complicated, I tend to just create a Test version of the interface (e.g. `ILogger`), and register the arguments I'm interested in from the calls there, and check on those.

Comment: But OP wants to check `LogLevel.Critical`, I guess

Comment: "If it gets too complicated, I tend to just create a Test version of the interface" 
This is most excellent advice! Mocking libraries automate this process; for cases that need more custom logic creating a custom mock is usually a much better alternative.